# numpy get index where value is true

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

```
>>> ex=np.arange(30)
>>> e=np.reshape(ex,[3,10])
>>> e
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
>>> e>15
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
         True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True]], dtype=bool)
```

I need to find the rows that have true or rows in `e` whose value are more than 15. I could iterate using a for loop, however, I would like to know if there is a way numpy could do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

To get the row numbers where at least one item is larger than 15:

```
>>> np.where(np.any(e>15, axis=1))
(array([1, 2], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: The [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) documentation states: *"When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for* `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()`. **Using [`nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) directly should be preferred**, *as it behaves correctly for subclasses."*

Answer (score 119):

You can use the [`nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) function. it returns the nonzero indices of the given input.

**Easy Way**

```
>>> (e > 15).nonzero()

(array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), array([6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

to see the indices more cleaner, use `transpose` method:

```
>>> numpy.transpose((e>15).nonzero())

[[1 6]
 [1 7]
 [1 8]
 [1 9]
 [2 0]
 ...
```

**Not Bad Way**

```
>>> numpy.nonzero(e > 15)

(array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), array([6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

or the clean way:

```
>>> numpy.transpose(numpy.nonzero(e > 15))

[[1 6]
 [1 7]
 [1 8]
 [1 9]
 [2 0]
 ...
```

Comment: `np.nonzero()` is what `np.where()` uses [under the hood](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Comment: `np.transpose(np.where(board==0))` is what worked for me

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that you need to transpose the array. I spent half an hour questioning my sanity on why it returns indices that dont exist.

Comment: Whoa, numpy makes it really hard!! they could have followed pandas' philosophy, i.e., `(e > 15).index` and done!!! while much more pythonic!

Answer (score 68):

**A simple and clean way:** use [`np.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) to group the indices by element, rather than dimension as in `np.nonzero(a)` (i.e., `np.argwhere` returns a row for each non-zero element).

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> np.argwhere(a>4)
array([[5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

`np.argwhere(a)` is almost the same as `np.transpose(np.nonzero(a))`, but it produces a result of the correct shape for a 0-d array.

**Note:** You cannot use `a(np.argwhere(a>4))` to get the corresponding values in `a`. The recommended way is to use `a[(a>4).astype(bool)]` or `a[(a>4) != 0]` rather than `a[np.nonzero(a>4)]` as they handle 0-d arrays correctly. See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero) for more details. As can be seen in the following example, `a[(a>4).astype(bool)]` and `a[(a>4) != 0]` can be simplified to `a[a>4]`.

**Another example:**

```
>>> a = np.array([5,-15,-8,-5,10])
>>> a
array([  5, -15,  -8,  -5,  10])
>>> a > 4
array([ True, False, False, False,  True])
>>> a[a > 4]
array([ 5, 10])
>>> a = np.add.outer(a,a)
>>> a
array([[ 10, -10,  -3,   0,  15],
       [-10, -30, -23, -20,  -5],
       [ -3, -23, -16, -13,   2],
       [  0, -20, -13, -10,   5],
       [ 15,  -5,   2,   5,  20]])
>>> a = np.argwhere(a>4)
>>> a
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 0],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 4]])
>>> for i,j in a: print(i,j)
... 
0 0
0 4
3 4
4 0
4 3
4 4
```

Comment: You mention that `np.argwhere(a)` is almost the same as `np.transpose(np.nonzero(a))`. It would be helpful if you could clarify in what way they are different.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer `np.flatnonzero(arr)` to the `nonzero()` option when you only need the row idx. `arr.nonzero()` works, but it returns a tuple instead of an array. `flatnonzero()` is equivalent to `np.nonzero(np.ravel(arr))[0]`.

As mentioned in the comments, `np.where()` is discouraged by the NumPy docs.