# List all x,y of coordinates having specific value in 2D array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to find a "more numpy" than loop&if solution for the task of list all (x,y) of coordinates having value equal to given m in 2D array python.

e.g: this is a 4x4 matrix

```
0 1 1 0
0 2 2 0
0 2 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

and if `m = 2`, I want the list of `[(1,1), (1,2), (2,1)]` since those cells = 2. what I want is their coordinates.

and if `m = 1` then `[(0,1), (0,2), (2,2)]` due to cells = 1.

I don't want solution of looping and if and put i,j into the list. It's a bit slow, any solution using numpy for faster ?
Thanks

Some suggest me to take a look at this [numpy get index where value is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094563/numpy-get-index-where-value-is-true) but I tried and it doesn't correct.

To be detail:

`np.where(np.any(e==1, axis=0)` in the case give out: [1,2] Yes! agree

`np.where(np.any(e==1, axis=1)` give out: [0,2] Yes! still ok BUT
it doesn't lead to this: `[(0,1), (0,2), (2,2)]` because row or column info is not enough,

So please don't underestimate this question and delete my question again and again. I'm tired of it

Comment: Your linked question does recommend `argwhere` or `transpose(where())`, same as your accepted answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy get index where value is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094563/numpy-get-index-where-value-is-true)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lose the `np.any` part. Like this:

```
np.array(np.where(e==1)).T
```

The external `np.array` and the transpose `.T` are just to arrange the indices in a way that will be easy for you to read.

Comment: `np.argwhere` uses `np.transpose(np.nonzero(cond))` to return this.