# Retrieve indices of certain value in a matrix and put it in a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this matrix; let's say there are hundreds of x value and thousands of y lists inside this matrix:

```
[[100   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0 100   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0   0 100 ...   0   0   0]
 ...
 [  0   0   0 ... 100   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0 100   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0 100]]
```

How will I be able to retrieve the index of `value >= 90` and put it in a nested list?

Here is the sample output:

```
[[0], [1, 167], [2, 498, 2890] ... [6568, 99998], [7894, 19695, 99999], [873, 100000]]
```

Comment: That is numpy 2D array ?

Comment: @azro <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: See my answer that use the power of numpy arrays, so much faster than python lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using nested list comprehension:

```
[[idx for idx, value in enumerate(row) if value >= 90] for row in arr]
```

To have the result of @azro's, I'd rather use:

```
np.argwhere(arr >= 90)
```

Answer (score 1):

The post *[numpy get index where value is true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16094563)* might help

> `numpy.transpose((array > value).nonzero())`

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([[1, 76, 987, 1, 1, 1], [876, 76, 765, 1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 123]])

result = np.transpose((values > 90).nonzero())
print(result)
```

```
[[0 2]
 [1 0]
 [1 2]
 [5 5]]
```

Comment: 1) This isn't the OP's desired output 2) Using numpy I'd rather use `argwhere`, like in my answer.