# Printing indices corresponding to a criterion in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `T`. I am printing all values which meet the criterion: `T<5`. However, I don't know how to print the corresponding indices of values meeting this criterion. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
T=np.array([4.7,5.1,2.9])
T1=T[T<5]
print([T1])
```

The expected output is

```
J=[0,2]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy get index where value is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094563/numpy-get-index-where-value-is-true)

Answer (score 1):

Try [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html): `np.flatnonzero(T<5)`

Answer (score 0):

`argwhere` does that for you
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html

```
x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

np.argwhere(x>1)
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

The meaning of output is:

- row 0 element 2
- row 1 element 0
- row 1 element 1
- row 1 element 2